# Perl one-liner idiomatic syntax

Tags: perl

In perl both:

```
if (!$var) { $var = 24 }
```

and :

```
if (!$var) { $var = 24; }
```

Are correct, when I expected only the second one to work.

Which one is the most idiomatic syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are correct, as you noticed. You don't need to end your last statement within a block with a semicolon, but it's good practice.

Here are a few ways to rewrite your if statement:

```
$var = 24 if !$var;
$var = 24 unless $var;
$var ||= 24;
```

Comment: `//=` might be worth including for perl 5.10.

Comment: I have tried ''//='' and ''||='' on perl 5.10 on CentOS 6 and both work without issues. Maybe it is a Red Hat backport?

Comment: Please note that there is a tiny difference between ||= and //=. For $var equal to 0, $var ||= 24 will change the value of $var, while $var //= 24 will not change $var's value.

Answer (score 13):

First, `if (!$var) { $var = 24; }` on a single-line with or without semi-colons is not idiomatic in Perl.

As you have noticed, the semi-colon is not necessary, because, in Perl, semi-colons are statement separators, not statement terminators.

Your question has 'one-liner' in the title, but I can't figure out what this has to do with one-liners. If there is a reason to use the full `if condition block` syntax, then don't put it on a single line. Instead:

```
if (!$var) {
    $var = 24;
}
```

Presumably, you are using the block because you might add other statements in it. This will make your diffs cleaner.

On the other hand, the statement is only meant to set `$var` and nothing else when `$var` is false or undefined, then you should use:

```
$var ||= 24;
```

over other methods because this is the clearest statement of intent. If the idea is to only set `$var` when it is not defined, you can use:

```
 $var //= 24;
```

with 5.10 and later.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, most people include the semi-colon, though one of the following might be more idiomatic in this case:

```
$var = 24 if !$var;
$var = 24 unless $var;
$var ||= 24;
```

(Some people hate `unless`, though.)

---

Not quite as many, but quite a few, also include a trailing comma in lists spanning multiple lines.

```
my @foo = (
   "abc def",
   "ghi jkl",
   "mno pqr",
);
```

This reduces the number of changed lines when adding to the list, and makes it easier to do so.

Answer (score 3):

From [perldoc perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html):

> Every simple statement must be terminated with a semicolon,
>   unless it is the final statement in a block, in which case the semicolon is optional.
>   But put the semicolon in anyway if the block takes up more than one line,
>   because you may eventually add another line.

I prefer to add semicolon always.